# Modify the interface of Skype

Tags: android, skype

can I create an android application which can change the interface of Skype ???

Note : I make a research and I found that it's impossible, because each application in android is associated with a unique UID and this prevents one application from modifying the file of another app.

Comment: This would be a significant problem in terms of security if applications could do this. You cannot do this.

Comment: thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an application that modifies another application's interface and distribute it via Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Xposed. It requires a rooted device though.

Here is a tutorial to get you started https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial